# Poisson brackets

Tags: homework-and-exercises, hamiltonian-formalism, coordinate-systems, phase-space, poisson-brackets

> I want to find out,for which constants (the greek letters) is this transformation canonical: $$Q^1 = \alpha q^1, Q^2 = q^2 + \beta (q^1)^3, P_1 = p_1 + \gamma (q^1)^2p_2\text{ and }P_2 = \delta p_2~?$$

And I would examine the Poisson brackets for that: $[Q^1,Q^2] = 0$, $[P_1,P_2] = 0$, $[Q^1, P_1] = 1$, $[Q^2, P_2] = 1$, $[Q^1,P_2] = 1$, $[Q^2,P_1] = 1$.

I struggle with $[Q^1, P_2]$ where i get 0, instead of 1 equal to some constant. Does it mean the transformation cannot be canonical at all? I calculated this bracket as $[Q^1, P_2]= \frac {\partial Q^1 } {\partial q^1}\frac {\partial P_2 } {\partial p_1} - \frac {\partial Q^1 } {\partial p_1}\frac {\partial P_2 } {\partial q^1} + \frac {\partial Q^1 } {\partial q^2} \frac {\partial P_2 } {\partial p_2} - \frac {\partial Q^1 } {\partial p_2}\frac {\partial P_2 } {\partial q^2} =0$

Did I understand this problem incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error lies in the assumption $[Q^1,P_2]=1$. The fundamental bracket between the coordinates $Q^i$ and the impulses $P_j$ is given by $$[Q^i,P_j]=\delta^i_j.$$
The $\delta_j^i$ symbol is $1$ when $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise: this means that the bracket $[Q^1,P_2]$ is $0$, and in your case this holds automatically, for any value of the constants.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out, $\alpha = 1$, $\delta = 1$ and $\beta, \gamma = 0$